# FileLoaderLoadException when rendering new template symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I am new and trying to enhance my knowledge to this framework. Having a difficulty in rendering a template, it gives me an error:

> FileLoaderLoadException ERROR 64] XML declaration allowed only at the
>   start of the document (in n/a - line 2, column 6) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\config\routes/routes.xml (which is loaded in
>   resource "C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\config\routes/routes.xml")

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/homepage", name="user")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
}
```

**YAML**

```
user:
    path:     /homepage
    controller: App\Controller\UserController::index
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="user" path="/homepage">
        <default key="_controller">App\Controller\Userontroller::index</default>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Question: How can I solve this? Is there something I missed causing this error?

Comment: <default key="_controller">App\Controller\Userontroller::index</default>

Maybe there is need to be "UserController"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't understand how does works the routing in Symfony and It's normal for newcomers.

Routing is very easy, you have to define it (in yaml OR XML OR PHP OR annotations) not All just one of them :-).

The best practices recommend to use annotations so comment your yaml and remove XML files and follow the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)

```
/**
 * @Route("/homepage", name="user")
 */
```

/homepage means that this url matches this function and 
 name="user" It's the path name in twig like this

```
<a href="{{ path('user') }}">User page</a>
```

Comment: After doing that and execute the command of composer require annotations. What next? I have background to MVC, routing because I've already tried CI and Laravel framework.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException No route found for "GET /user". I checked my routes by using debug:route. It indicates any any any /homepage

Comment: I updated my answer please read it, to access to this function's controller the url is /homepage and not /user . user is the path name variable acessible in twig :-)

Comment: So /homepage will be my url? http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage then the name="user" it will execute the path in my routes.yaml?

Comment: If you are using annotations like you did, forget routes.yaml, you said "So /homepage will be my url? 127.0.0.1:8000/homepage" Yes it's true ! The name="user" is to define the route name in twig (href link) or in your controller ($this->redirectToRoute('user'))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162432/discussion-between-angel-and-smaine).

Comment: When I change my redirectToRoute('homepage') into user it will give me an error "redirected you too many times."